# With AWS ELB, is it possible to direct specific subdirectories to specific servers?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We're moving from a single EC2 server setup to a multiple-webserver setup, and using ELB to spread traffic across the servers.

Our core application will handle this just fine.  There's one sub directory that hosts a different application, and I'd like all requests for that application to go to a specific server.

Is this possible with ELB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon's ELB operates at the IP level, it doesn't care about the protocol running on top.

What you're looking for is a HTTP reverse proxy. You could run another two EC2 instances with something like Apache, Nginx or Varnish to decides which back end instances to use based on the directory structure. Then you could use ELB to balance between these.